# create data.frame based on two data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe

This question is super simple but I don't get the way of doing it without using a for loop that iterates column by column

I have two data.frames with same index column and different columns. I want to create a new data.frame comparing values in both data.frames and if value in `dfB` is greater than `dfA` then assign a `1` otherwise a `0`. Column names are equal in both data.frames and both have same number of rows.

The data.frames are very simple, an example here:

```
dfA=data.frame(index=1:5, B=c(0,0,1,0,2), C=c(0,0,0,0,1))
dfB=data.frame(index=1:5, B=c(1,1,2,0,2), C=c(0,1,0,2,1))

> dfA
index B C
    1 0 0
    2 0 0
    3 1 0
    4 0 0
    5 2 1


> dfB
index B C
   1 1 0
   2 1 1
   3 2 0
   4 0 2
   5 2 1
```

The result should be this:

```
> dfC
index B C
   1 1 0
   2 1 1
   3 1 0
   4 0 1
   5 0 0
```

Comment: You can do in one line also: `df=data.frame(1*(dfA[,-1]<dfB[,-1]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
dfA=data.frame(index=1:5, B=c(0,0,1,0,2), C=c(0,0,0,0,1))
dfB=data.frame(index=1:5, B=c(1,1,2,0,2), C=c(0,1,0,2,1))

dfC <- data.frame(ifelse(dfB[-1]>dfA[-1],1,0))
```

The result is:

```
  B C
1 1 0
2 1 1
3 1 0
4 0 1
5 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data.frames are as shown in the example you could do:

```
dfC <- dfA
dfC[-1] <- as.integer(dfB[-1] > dfA[-1])
dfC
  index B C
1     1 1 0
2     2 1 1
3     3 1 0
4     4 0 1
5     5 0 0
```

`[-1]` on a `data.frame` selects the whole data.frame except the first column.